# Matrix.CreateScale only scaling with full numbers

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, zooming, scale

I've been trying to zoom in and out on my objects by using the Matrix.CreateScale() function, using it like this:

```
Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 0))
```

But, I've noticed that when I tried to make Zoom 1,5 it doesn't do anything, only at the numbers 1 or 2, but when it reaches that it's too big/small, how do I zoom in and out without taking such big steps, how do I make it take less steps?

```
   public float Zoom
    {
        get { return zoom; }
        set { zoom = value; }
    }


    public Matrix get_transformation(GraphicsDeviceManager graphicsDevice)
    {
        transform =
          Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-pos.X, -pos.Y, 0)) *
                                     Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) *
                                     Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 0)) *
                                     Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(graphicsDevice.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.0f, graphicsDevice.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.0f, 0));
        return transform;
    }

        //zooming
        float scrollValue = Mouse.GetState().ScrollWheelValue / 480;
        Core.cam.Zoom = scrollValue;
```

Basically, each time I scroll it will increase the zoom value by 0.25, and should do something, but it will only do something after 4 scrolls (4*0.25 = 1)

Edit:

Fixed it by changing

```
float scrollValue = Mouse.GetState().ScrollWheelValue / 480;
```

to

```
float scrollValue = Mouse.GetState().ScrollWheelValue / 480f;
```

Comment: This should work. The only thing I can imagine is something related with your World/View/Projection matrix, can you give more code? mainly how you is applying this matrix on the models.

Comment: @greenboxal I'm not applying it to any 3D models, I created a camera for 2D purposes, and trying to get a working zoom into it now, but I'll post some code how I'm applying it too then.

Comment: Weird, it should work fine. Anyway, I don't know if I understood it correctly. If you scale with 10 it's applied, but if you scale with 10.1 is the same as not applying the scale?

Comment: @greenboxal I'll post my code how I'm applying the zoom value too, just a second, I'm doing it so that I can do it with the scrollwheel.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't with the Matrix multiplication(that doesn't make sense), are you sure that you rebuild the Matrix that you use after each update on Zoom?

Comment: @greenboxal I fixed it, at the line         float scrollValue = Mouse.GetState().ScrollWheelValue / 480;, I had to add an f behind the 480, now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help though!